# Comparing 2 arrays and adding similar values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have 2 arrays in PHP.  One of them holds a list of dates, the other a list of numbers.

```
   Array1
    (
        [0] => 2010-06-14
        [1] => 2010-06-14
        [2] => 2010-06-14
        [3] => 2014-01-26
        [4] => 2014-01-26
    )
   Array2
    (
        [0] => 120
        [1] => 100
        [2] => 60
        [3] => 140
        [4] => 30
    )
```

The value [0] in Array2 belongs with the date [0] in Array1.  What I am trying to do is add all of the values in Array2 together, based on the date.  Any dates that match should have their values added together.  So for example at the end I would like something like:

```
$date = 2010-06-14;
$value = 280;

$date = 2014-01-26;
$value = 170;
```

...and so on.

I've searched though the site but was unable to find exactly what I needed.  Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate `$values`, and get the corresponding date from `$dates` to use as the key in your result array.

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {    
    $result[$dates[$key]] = $value + ($result[$dates[$key]] ?? 0);    
}
```

The output will be like this:

```
array (size=2)
  '2010-06-14' => int 280
  '2014-01-26' => int 170
```

Comment: Hello, yes this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you.  I tested this out, however, I think there is a slight bug.  It seems the last $value is not getting added.  In the example above, 2014-01-26 would equal 140.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think I should be safe using: for ($i = 0; $i < count($weeklyDataDate)+1; $i++)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count(Array1); $i++) {
  $newArray[$Array1[$i]] = $Array2[$i];
}

echo $newArray[$date1] + $newArray[$date2];
```

Put the dates as keys to for easy math.

Comment: What are you doing? How do this compute sum of values? Please add some explanation and samples (maybe compare your result with attended effects)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum=0;              // New Element
$Array3[][]=0;       // New 2D array

$p=0;                                  // Counter for 2D array
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)                   // Single loop for traversing
{
$date=Array1[$i];                     // Start for a date
while($date==Array1[$i]){             // For for Similar date
$sum=$sum+Array2[$i];                 // Adding values of similar date
$i++;                                 // Increment array
}
$Array3[$p]["date"]=$date;            // Array3 date element
$Array3[$p]["sum"]=$sum;              // Array4 date element
$i--;                                 // Reducing a value which is incremented in while loop
}
```

Array3 is like

```
Array3
    (
        [0] => array( 'date' => "  ",'sum' => " ")
        [1] => array( 'date' => "  ",'sum' => " ")
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count all of the values in **Array2** that have an entry in **Array1** that matches some predefined **target value**?

If so, this **for loop version** should work:

```
private function forLoopVersion($array1, $array2, $target) {
 $result = 0;
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); ++$i) {
  if ($array1[$i] == $target) {
    $result += $array2[$i];
  }
 }
 return $result;
}
```

Also, this **foreach loop version** might work, but I do not know if the `$key` for `$array1` can be used to index an element in `$array2`. You could try it:

```
private function foreachLoopVersion($array1, $array2, $target) {
 $result = 0;
 foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == $target) {
    $result += $array2[$key];
  }
 }
 return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't have a predefined target value.  Array1 contains several hundred dates, and Array2 contains sever hundred values.  The keys across the two arrays will always match.  For example, the date in Array1[50] will go with the value in Array2[50]. I need to go through Array1 and match all of the dates, then add all of the values from Array2 together.  So if the dates for Array1[29] and [30] match, the values from Array2[29] and [30] should be added together.  I hope this makes sense.